# MySQL query with multiple INNER JOIN returns duplicate entries in the result

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I have the following data structure:

There are multiple tables:

I need the following return: sum of balance (sum(a.balance) as pnl) from tabposition.

However, this query returns duplicate results. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks

```
SET @dt_inicio := '2021-12-01'; 
SET @dt_fim := '2021-12-09';    

select a.data, a.fund, 'CASH-USD' as ticker , 'CASH' as strategy, 'Dolar Cash' as company, 
'Others' as type, 'Others' as sector, 
    sum(a.balance) as pnl from tabposition as a    
inner join tablistaativos as c on a.ticker = c.ticker    
inner join tabdiautil as d on a.data = d.data_util    
inner join tabhistorynav as e on a.data = e.data    
inner join tabhistorynav as f on d.data_util_ant = f.data     
inner join tabprice as g on a.data = g.data    
inner join tabprice as i on d.data_util_ant = i.data     
inner join tabhistorynav as j on d.data_util_ant = j.data and a.fund = j.fund     
inner join tabfatorx as l on a.data = l.data_pos    
where a.data >= @dt_inicio and a.data <= @dt_fim and a.fund = 'TORK FUND' and a.qnt <> 0    
and (c.class = 'ACCO' or c.class = 'ACCOUNTING' or c.class = 'SPAC' or c.class = 'ACOES' or   
c.class = 'OPCOES' or c.class = 'FUNDO')    
and e.official = 'Yes' and e.fund = 'TORK FIA' and f.official = 'Yes' and f.fund = 'TORK FIA'     
and g.ticker = 'usdbrl' and i.ticker = 'usdbrl'    
and l.cotista = 'TORK FIA'    
group by a.data   
order by a.data
```

Comment: is `a.data`  a unique column to group by ?

Comment: Andreas, it was a typo. Just fixed it. Thanks for pointing my mistake.

Comment: @Faesal, yes it is!

Comment: one of the tables must contains more than 1 related records related to `c.ticker` and `a.data` and they are different, try to remove one by one and see which one causes this, then come to discuss the solution.

Comment: @Faesal you are right. when i take "inner join tabhistorynav as j on d.data_util_ant = j.data and a.fund = j.fund " off the query, it works

Comment: so it's solved or not ?

Comment: could tell why you need fund how it looks like to be able to help ?

Comment: @Faesal not really.. stiil not working even i know the problem is there

Comment: @Faesal i need it because there are different funds o n the table and i needt to point to a specific one

Comment: i substituted that part to "inner join (select y.data as dia, y.fund as fundo, y.nav from tabhistorynav as y inner join tabdiautil as z on y.data = z.data_util_ant where y.official = 'Yes') as j on a.fund = fundo and a.data = dia" and it worked. Thank you for your help.